# Django form is sent but doesent save to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, django

I´m doing a simple user-business application, where a user has one or many business. The problem is that my create business forms is not saving its data to the database. The user has all the permissions and is active, and I can save data from the create user form with no problem. What is wrong?
**View.py:**

```
 class crear_negocio(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "tienda/crear_negocio.html"
    form_class= Negocio_Form
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tienda_app:crear_negocio')
    login_url = reverse_lazy('register_app:logIn')
```

**form.py:**

```
class Negocio_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Negocio_Model
        fields = ("Nombre_Negocio","Administrador","Descipcion_Negocio",'Correo_Negocio','Telefono_Negocio','Direccion_Negocio')
```

**Model.py:**

```
class Negocio_Model(models.Model):
    Nombre_Negocio = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Administrador = models.ForeignKey(Usuario_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Descipcion_Negocio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    Correo_Negocio = models.EmailField()
    Telefono_Negocio = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    Direccion_Negocio = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nombre_Negocio+' '+self.Correo_Negocio+' '+self.Telefono_Negocio+' '+self.Direccion_Negocio
```

**Database config:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'bdtg1',
        'USER':'juan',
        'PASSWORD':'juanjo123',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306'
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have , forms, views and models .js and not .py ?

Comment: My bad, .py alrready edited, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FormView` does not `.save()` the form, thus it will indeed not create a record at the database. By default in case the form is successful, it redirects to the success URL, that's all. A typical use case of a `FormView` is for example to send an email instead of saving it to the database.

You can override the [**`form_valid(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid) to save the form, but it might be better to make use of a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class crear_negocio(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'tienda/crear_negocio.html'
    form_class= Negocio_Form
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tienda_app:crear_negocio')
    login_url = reverse_lazy('register_app:logIn')
```

Comment: That was it, I did it that way because I edited the user manager so it wasnt a problem for users. Thank you very much!